# how to use self join here to produce the desired output

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have table structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Item
(
  ItemKey BIGINT,
  DisplayName VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO Item VALUES (136172,'Computer')
INSERT INTO Item VALUES (156737,'Car')

CREATE TABLE ItemTypeFactvw
(
   ItemKey BIGINT,
   TypeDimKey BIGINT
)

INSERT INTO ItemTypeFactvw VALUES (136172,483)
INSERT INTO ItemTypeFactvw VALUES (136172,1353)
INSERT INTO ItemTypeFactvw VALUES (156737,1000)

CREATE TABLE ItemTypeDimvw
(
  Id BIGINT,
  BaseId BIGINT,
  TypeDimKey BIGINT,
  DisplayName VARCHAR(100)

)

INSERT INTO ItemTypeDimvw VALUES (1,80,483,'IT Gadgets')
INSERT INTO ItemTypeDimvw VALUES (3,1,1353,'Electronics')
INSERT INTO ItemTypeDimvw VALUES (2,44,1000,'Vehicle')
```

I need to product the result like this (desired output):

```
| ITEMKEY | DISPLAYNAME | TYPEDIMKEY | ID | BASEID | ITEM BASE TYPE |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|  136172 |    Computer |        483 |  1 |     80 |    Electronics |
|  156737 |         Car |       1000 |  2 |     44 |        Vehicle |
```

This is the query i have:

```
SELECT i.ItemKey, 
        i.DisplayName, 
        it.TypeDimKey,
        itd.Id,
        itd.BaseId,
        itd.DisplayName 'Item Base Type'
  FROM Item i
INNER JOIN ItemTypeFactvw it
on i.ItemKey = it.ItemKey
INNER JOIN  ItemTypeDimvw itd
ON itd.TypeDimKey = it.TypeDimKey
```

Above query does not produce the desired output as it also brings an additional record from `ItemTypeDimvw` where `DisplayName` is `"IT Gadgets"`.

think of this as a class hierarchy. IT Gadgets Inherits from Electronics. So i need to display the base type in this case it is Electronics for IT Gadgets

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef094/1

Comment: What is the logic behind getting the desired result?

Comment: think of this as a class hierarchy. IT Gadgets Inherits from Electronics. So i need to display the base type in this case it is Electronics for IT Gadgets.

Comment: Including that in your OP as well as what version of SQL Server would be helpful in answering your question. :)

Comment: @bluefeet - updated the question and tags

Comment: I'm not sure how you can exclude the 'IT Gadgets' record.  If it isn't the same kind of thing as the 'Electronics' record, maybe it doesn't belong in the same table?  I'm wondering if the database structure here has a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
select  i.ItemKey, 
        i.DisplayName, 
        it.TypeDimKey,
        itd.Id,
        itd.BaseId,
        itd.DisplayName 'Item Base Type'
  from Item i
inner join ItemTypeFactvw it
on i.ItemKey = it.ItemKey
inner join ItemTypeDimvw itd
on itd.TypeDimKey = it.TypeDimKey
left outer join ItemTypeDimvw itd2
on itd2.id = itd.BaseId
where itd2.id is null
```

Comment: it does work on the given example but does not work on the actual data as itd2.BaseId is never null. It does have some other record as its base. may be i did not represent the data structure properly.